# how to report column across not down in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports-xi

I need create a crystal report to report the column across not down. The report itself is very simple, there is no need to group and summarize. The only thing is different from regular report is it need display the column across rather than down. I try use cross-tab, or multiple columns with no success. is there any way i can make is down in crystal? Thanks

The regular report with column down:

[image]

I need display like these:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try the following
put the the 4th names of the first column in the page header and make that section underlay the following section, then create 4 details sections, one per column and put the values values right next below and make the details to grow across then down.
for instance
page header

```
Mth
Vendor
Trans#
Amt
end of page header
details1   date field
details2   vendor field
details3   trans field
details4   amt field
```